# In Haskell, how can I get a substring of a Text between two indices?

Tags: string, haskell, slice

I'm trying to fint the Haskell equivalent of the Python:

```
>>>"This is a test"[5:9]
'is a'
```

I'm using the `Data.Text` module, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also, you can define the function in terms of `Data.Text.take` and `drop`, both functions from `Data.Text` library:

```
slice :: Int -> Int -> Text -> Text
slice a b = (Data.Text.take (b - a)) . (Data.Text.drop a)
```

Answer (score 7):

Usually one uses [**`drop :: Int -> Text -> Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:drop) and [**`take :: Int -> Text -> Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:take) to obtain a slice of the subtext. We can combine the two to make some sort of `substring`:

```
import Data.Text as Tx(Text, drop, take)

substring :: Int -> Int -> Tx.Text -> Tx.Text
substring start length = Tx.take length . Tx.drop start
```

or if we want to use the end index (exclusive), we can create a `slice` function:

```
import Data.Text as Tx(drop, take)

slice :: Int -> Int -> Tx.Text -> Tx.Text
slice start end = Tx.take (end-start) . Tx.drop start
```

We then can use it like:

```
Prelude Tx> slice 5 9 "This is a test"
"is a"
```

This is not *fully* equivalent to Python's slice notation, since for instance Python uses negative indices as a way to count from the last element (i.e. `-1` is the last element), and we can use `'foobar'[-5:-2]` to obtain a slice that where the indices mean "*taking a slice from the* last but four *to the* last but one *element*".

Answer (score 5):

Simple using the `take` function:

```
substring :: Int -> Int -> Text -> Text
substring start end text = take (end - start) (drop start text)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import Data.List

substring :: Int -> Int -> String -> String

substring i j s = take (j-i) ( drop i s )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the dot operator and sections gives a nice definition with `take` and `drop`:

```hs
slice off n = (take n).(drop off)
```

You can then just use `slice 2 3 "hello!"` to get `"llo"`